# Entity Framework multiple aggregation performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6

I have a question about entity framework query building.

## Schema

I have a table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataLogger](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [bigint] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DCDistributionBox](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DataLoggerID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DCDistributionBox]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DCDistributionBox_DataLogger] FOREIGN KEY([DataLoggerID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[DataLogger] ([ID])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DCString] (
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DCDistributionBoxID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CurrentMPP] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DCString]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DCString_DCDistributionBox] FOREIGN KEY([DCDistributionBoxID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[DCDistributionBox] ([ID])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StringData](
    [DCStringID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DCCurrent] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey4] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [TimeStamp] DESC, [DCStringID] ASC)
)
```

The `[StringData]` table as has following storage stats:

- Data space: 26,901.86 MB
- Row count: 131,827,749
- Partitioned: true
- Partition count: 62

## Usage

I now want to group the data in the `[StringData]` table and do some aggregation.

In pure SQL it would look like this:

```
declare @projectID bigint = 20686;
declare @from datetime = '06.02.2016';
declare @till datetime = '07.02.2016';
declare @interval int = 15;

SELECT 
DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [StringData].[TimeStamp] ) / @interval * @interval, 0) AS [TimeStamp]
, AVG([StringData].[DCCurrent] / [DCString].[CurrentMPP]) AS [DCCurrentAvg]
, MIN([StringData].[DCCurrent] / [DCString].[CurrentMPP]) AS [DCCurrentMin]
, MAX([StringData].[DCCurrent] / [DCString].[CurrentMPP]) AS [DCCurrentMax]
, STDEV([StringData].[DCCurrent] / [DCString].[CurrentMPP]) AS [DCCurrentStDev]
, COUNT(*) AS [Count]

FROM [StringData]
JOIN [DCString] ON [DCString].[ID] = [StringData].[DCStringID]
JOIN [DCDistributionBox] ON [DCDistributionBox].[ID] = [DCString].[DCDistributionBoxID]
JOIN [DataLogger] ON [DataLogger].[ID] = [DCDistributionBox].[DataLoggerID]

WHERE [DataLogger].[ProjectID] = @projectID
AND [StringData].[TimeStamp] >= @from
AND [StringData].[TimeStamp] < @till

GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [StringData].[TimeStamp] ) / @interval * @interval, 0)
```

**Excecution timespan:** 653ms

Now I created a Entity Framework equivalent (I thought):

```
var compareData = model.StringDatas
    AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p => p.DCString.DCDistributionBox.DataLogger.ProjectID == projectID && p.TimeStamp >= from && p.TimeStamp < till)                    
    .Select(d => new
    {
        TimeStamp = d.Key,
        DCCurrentMin = d.Min(v => v.DCCurrent / v.DCString.CurrentMPP),
        DCCurrentMax = d.Max(v => v.DCCurrent / v.DCString.CurrentMPP),
        DCCurrentAvg = d.Average(v => v.DCCurrent / v.DCString.CurrentMPP),
        DCCurrentStDev = DbFunctions.StandardDeviation(d.Select(v => v.DCCurrent / v.DCString.CurrentMPP))
    })
    .ToList();
```

And the result of excecution was a timeout (longer the 30 seconds)!?

## Attempts

I now took a look into the Entity Framework generated SQL query and looks like this:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Project10].[C1] AS [C2], 
[Project10].[C2] AS [C3], 
[Project10].[C3] AS [C4], 
[Project10].[C4] AS [C5], 
[Project10].[C5] AS [C6]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project8].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project8].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project8].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project8].[C4] AS [C4], 
    (SELECT 
        STDEV([Project9].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project9].[DCCurrent] / [Project9].[CurrentMPP] AS [A1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent17].[DCStringID] AS [DCStringID], 
                [Extent17].[DCCurrent] AS [DCCurrent], 
                [Extent18].[ID] AS [ID], 
                [Extent18].[CurrentMPP] AS [CurrentMPP]
                FROM    [dbo].[StringData] AS [Extent17]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCString] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent17].[DCStringID] = [Extent18].[ID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCDistributionBox] AS [Extent19] ON [Extent18].[DCDistributionBoxID] = [Extent19].[ID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataLogger] AS [Extent20] ON [Extent19].[DataLoggerID] = [Extent20].[ID]
                WHERE (([Extent20].[ProjectID] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent20].[ProjectID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent17].[TimeStamp] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent17].[TimeStamp] < @p__linq__2) AND (([Project8].[C1] = (DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Extent17].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3))) OR (([Project8].[C1] IS NULL) AND (DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Extent17].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3) IS NULL)))
            )  AS [Project9]
        )  AS [Project9]) AS [C5]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project6].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [Project6].[C3] AS [C3], 
        (SELECT 
            AVG([Project7].[A1]) AS [A1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project7].[DCCurrent] / [Project7].[CurrentMPP] AS [A1]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Extent13].[DCStringID] AS [DCStringID], 
                    [Extent13].[DCCurrent] AS [DCCurrent], 
                    [Extent14].[ID] AS [ID], 
                    [Extent14].[CurrentMPP] AS [CurrentMPP]
                    FROM    [dbo].[StringData] AS [Extent13]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCString] AS [Extent14] ON [Extent13].[DCStringID] = [Extent14].[ID]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCDistributionBox] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[DCDistributionBoxID] = [Extent15].[ID]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataLogger] AS [Extent16] ON [Extent15].[DataLoggerID] = [Extent16].[ID]
                    WHERE (([Extent16].[ProjectID] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent16].[ProjectID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent13].[TimeStamp] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent13].[TimeStamp] < @p__linq__2) AND (([Project6].[C1] = (DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Extent13].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3))) OR (([Project6].[C1] IS NULL) AND (DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Extent13].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3) IS NULL)))
                )  AS [Project7]
            )  AS [Project7]) AS [C4]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project4].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project4].[C2] AS [C2], 
            (SELECT 
                MAX([Project5].[A1]) AS [A1]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project5].[DCCurrent] / [Project5].[CurrentMPP] AS [A1]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Extent9].[DCStringID] AS [DCStringID], 
                        [Extent9].[DCCurrent] AS [DCCurrent], 
                        [Extent10].[ID] AS [ID], 
                        [Extent10].[CurrentMPP] AS [CurrentMPP]
                        FROM    [dbo].[StringData] AS [Extent9]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCString] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent9].[DCStringID] = [Extent10].[ID]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCDistributionBox] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent10].[DCDistributionBoxID] = [Extent11].[ID]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataLogger] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent11].[DataLoggerID] = [Extent12].[ID]
                        WHERE (([Extent12].[ProjectID] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent12].[ProjectID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent9].[TimeStamp] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent9].[TimeStamp] < @p__linq__2) AND (([Project4].[C1] = (DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Extent9].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3))) OR (([Project4].[C1] IS NULL) AND (DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Extent9].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3) IS NULL)))
                    )  AS [Project5]
                )  AS [Project5]) AS [C3]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
                (SELECT 
                    MIN([Project3].[A1]) AS [A1]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project3].[DCCurrent] / [Project3].[CurrentMPP] AS [A1]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [Extent5].[DCStringID] AS [DCStringID], 
                            [Extent5].[DCCurrent] AS [DCCurrent], 
                            [Extent6].[ID] AS [ID], 
                            [Extent6].[CurrentMPP] AS [CurrentMPP]
                            FROM    [dbo].[StringData] AS [Extent5]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCString] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[DCStringID] = [Extent6].[ID]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCDistributionBox] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[DCDistributionBoxID] = [Extent7].[ID]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataLogger] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent7].[DataLoggerID] = [Extent8].[ID]
                            WHERE (([Extent8].[ProjectID] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent8].[ProjectID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent5].[TimeStamp] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent5].[TimeStamp] < @p__linq__2) AND (([Project2].[C1] = (DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Extent5].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3))) OR (([Project2].[C1] IS NULL) AND (DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Extent5].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3) IS NULL)))
                        )  AS [Project3]
                    )  AS [Project3]) AS [C2]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1]
                    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                        DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Extent1].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3) AS [C1]
                        FROM    [dbo].[StringData] AS [Extent1]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCString] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[DCStringID] = [Extent2].[ID]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCDistributionBox] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[DCDistributionBoxID] = [Extent3].[ID]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataLogger] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[DataLoggerID] = [Extent4].[ID]
                        WHERE (([Extent4].[ProjectID] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent4].[ProjectID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[TimeStamp] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[TimeStamp] < @p__linq__2)
                    )  AS [Distinct1]
                )  AS [Project2]
            )  AS [Project4]
        )  AS [Project6]
    )  AS [Project8]
)  AS [Project10]
```

## Question

Why does Entity Framework seperates every aggregation into a sngle subselect and how can I avoid this to get a performance near to the raw SQL query?

#### Update 1

This has exact the same SQL query output and timeout result:

```
var query = from d in model.StringDatas
        where d.DCString.DCDistributionBox.DataLogger.ProjectID == projectID
        where d.TimeStamp >= fromDate
        where d.TimeStamp < tillDate
        group d by DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime.MinValue, DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(DateTime.MinValue, d.TimeStamp) / minuteInterval * minuteInterval) into g
        select new
        {
            TimeStamp = g.Key,
            DCCurrentMin = g.Min(v => v.DCCurrent / v.DCString.CurrentMPP),
            DCCurrentMax = g.Max(v => v.DCCurrent / v.DCString.CurrentMPP),
            DCCurrentAvg = g.Average(v => v.DCCurrent / v.DCString.CurrentMPP),
            DCCurrentStDev = DbFunctions.StandardDeviation(g.Select(v => v.DCCurrent / v.DCString.CurrentMPP))
        };

var queryResult= query.ToList();
```

Comment: try commenting out your calculation of DCCurrentStDev. I'm not sure how it would go about calculating that, and it may be what's throwing the whole thing off.

Comment: hi @shriop, tried it same result minus one subselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that behavior (bug?) when answering [How do I get EF6 to generate efficient SQL containing mulitple aggregate columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320252/how-do-i-get-ef6-to-generate-efficient-sql-containing-mulitple-aggregate-columns/35320905#35320905).

The only way I was able to resolve it was by introducing a temporary projection **before** the `group by` operation, and the same applies to your case:

```
var query =
    from e in (from d in db.StringDatas.AsNoTracking()
               where d.DCString.DCDistributionBox.DataLogger.ProjectID == projectID
                   && d.TimeStamp >= fromDate && d.TimeStamp < tillDate
               select new { d, s = d.DCString })
    group e by DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime.MinValue, DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(DateTime.MinValue, e.d.TimeStamp) / minuteInterval * minuteInterval) into g
    let ratio = g.Select(e => e.d.DCCurrent / e.s.CurrentMPP)
    select new
    {
        TimeStamp = g.Key,
        DCCurrentMin = ratio.Min(),
        DCCurrentMax = ratio.Max(),
        DCCurrentAvg = ratio.Average(),
        DCCurrentStDev = DbFunctions.StandardDeviation(ratio)
    };
```

EF generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [C2], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C3], 
    [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C4], 
    [GroupBy1].[A3] AS [C5], 
    [GroupBy1].[A4] AS [C6]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project1].[K1] AS [K1], 
        MIN([Project1].[A1]) AS [A1], 
        MAX([Project1].[A2]) AS [A2], 
        AVG([Project1].[A3]) AS [A3], 
        STDEV([Project1].[A4]) AS [A4]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            DATEADD (minute, ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__4, [Project1].[TimeStamp])) / @p__linq__5) * @p__linq__6, @p__linq__3) AS [K1], 
            [Project1].[DCCurrent] / [Project1].[CurrentMPP] AS [A1], 
            [Project1].[DCCurrent] / [Project1].[CurrentMPP] AS [A2], 
            [Project1].[DCCurrent] / [Project1].[CurrentMPP] AS [A3], 
            [Project1].[DCCurrent] / [Project1].[CurrentMPP] AS [A4]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[TimeStamp] AS [TimeStamp], 
                [Extent1].[DCCurrent] AS [DCCurrent], 
                [Extent2].[CurrentMPP] AS [CurrentMPP]
                FROM    [dbo].[StringDatas] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCStrings] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[DCStringID] = [Extent2].[ID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DCDistributionBoxes] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[DCDistributionBoxID] = [Extent3].[ID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataLoggers] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[DataLoggerID] = [Extent4].[ID]
                WHERE ([Extent4].[ProjectID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[TimeStamp] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[TimeStamp] < @p__linq__2)
            )  AS [Project1]
        )  AS [Project1]
        GROUP BY [K1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping the two properties you need rather than the whole object like this:

```
group new { d.DCCurrent, d.DCString.CurrentMPP }
```

Then change `v.DCString.CurrentMPP` to `v.CurrentMPP`

---

Try setting the [UseDatabaseNullSemantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx) to true.

This will eliminate all the `is null` checks and should allow the query optimizer to produce a similar execution plan to your original sql.

```
using(var model = new YourContext())
{
   model.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
   var query = from d in model.StringDatas
                ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aducci, tried it with same result. The generated SQL looked the same except for the  IS NULL checkups. Subselect still in there.

Comment: @SteffenMangold - Let me know if changing the `group` has any effect on performance