# EntityFramework LINQ query count fails but query returns result. How to optimize LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the below LINQ query that performs a self-left-outer-join. The querys looks a little complex but is simply doing a self join on itself(purpose if to join each record with the record for it previous business day) and then doing some parameterized filtering.

```
var newBreakThreshold = decimal.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewBreakThreshold"]);
using (var dbContext = new NavFoToBoCompareDbContext())
{
    var query = from current in dbContext.NAVSummaries
                let currentWD = SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", current.ValueDate)
                let currentPD = DbFunctions.AddDays(current.ValueDate, currentWD == 2 ? -3 : currentWD == 1 ? -2 : -1).Value
                join previous in dbContext.NAVSummaries
                on new { current.Portfolio, PD = currentPD }
                equals new { previous.Portfolio, PD = previous.ValueDate }
                into previousGroup
                from previous in previousGroup.DefaultIfEmpty() // LEFT OUTER JOIN
                select new { outer = current, inner = previous };

    if (dateStart.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(e => e.outer.ValueDate >= dateStart.Value);
    if (dateEnd.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(e => e.outer.ValueDate <= dateEnd.Value);
    if (!portfolio.Equals("ALL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        query = query.Where(e => e.outer.Portfolio.Equals(portfolio, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (!owner.Equals("ALL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        query = query.Where(e => e.outer.PortfolioOwner.Equals(owner, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (status != 0)
        query = query.Where(e => e.outer.Statuses.Any(s => s.StatusId == status));

    var query2 = query.Select(s => new
                {
                    BackOfficeNAV = s.outer.BackOfficeNAV,
                    FrontOfficeNAV = s.outer.FrontOfficeNAV,
                    Threshold = s.outer.Threshold,
                    ExtractId = s.outer.ExtractId,
                    ExtractStatus = s.outer.ExtractStatus,
                    PortfolioOwner = s.outer.PortfolioOwner,
                    DateTimeModified = s.outer.DateTimeModified,
                    MostCorrectNAV = s.outer.MostCorrectNAV,
                    Comments = s.outer.Comments,
                    Statuses = s.outer.Statuses,
                    Extracts = s.outer.Extracts,
                    Portfolio = s.outer.Portfolio,
                    ValueDate = s.outer.ValueDate,
                    DifferencePercent = s.outer.DifferencePercent,
                    DayOverDayChange = s.outer.DifferencePercent - s.inner.DifferencePercent,
                    IsChange = s.inner.DifferencePercent != s.outer.DifferencePercent,

                    PreviousValueDate = s.inner.ValueDate,
                    PreviousDifferencePercent = s.inner.DifferencePercent
                });


    query2 = query2.Where(r => "NEW".Equals(breakOption, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?
                                                ((r.DifferencePercent > r.Threshold) && r.IsChange && r.DayOverDayChange > newBreakThreshold) :
                                "OLD".Equals(breakOption, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? (r.DifferencePercent > r.Threshold) :
                                "ALL".Equals(breakOption, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    var resultCount = query2.Count();
}
```

The query is used in two places. In one method it used for computing the count required for pagination. In another method it is used for getting the actual results from the database. The implementation for getting the actual results for a bigger result set executes successfully, whereas the the Count() query fails with a Timeout exception. Note:Both implementations are exactly the same.

Can someone help me in optimizing this query as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tough (if not impossible) thing w/o having the real test environment. You may take a look at EF generated queries to see if something looks wrong. The `Count()` query should basically contain the LEFT OUTER semi-join plus WHERE.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the query generated. It executes successfully for a smaller date range which give lesser records. However, when I increase the date range, it throws an exception : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException -- Timeout expired.

Comment: Parameter sniffing? Bad cached plan (from the smaller date range)? Who knows:(

Comment: Relatively new terms for me though. But I hate to know that the LINQ without Count() executes successfully while with Count() doesn't. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure that's the problem, but at least let try to eliminate the potential effect of the so called [Parameter Sniffing Problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/) by eliminating the `dateStart` / `dateEnd` parameters by manually building expression with constant values.

First, a little helper method:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class QueryableUtils
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereBetween<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> dateSelector, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        if (startDate == null && endDate == null) return source;
        var startCond = startDate != null ? Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(dateSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(startDate.Value)) : null;
        var endCond = endDate != null ? Expression.LessThanOrEqual(dateSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(endDate.Value)) : null;
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            startCond == null ? endCond : endCond == null ? startCond : Expression.AndAlso(startCond, endCond),
            dateSelector.Parameters[0]);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Then try the following and see if it helps:

```
//if (dateStart.HasValue)
//    query = query.Where(e => e.outer.ValueDate >= dateStart.Value);
//if (dateEnd.HasValue)
//    query = query.Where(e => e.outer.ValueDate <= dateEnd.Value);
query = query.WhereBetween(e => e.outer.ValueDate, dateStart, dateEnd);
```

Comment: I think this worked. Not very sure though as I'll have to do some thorough testing. But I really appreciate for letting me know these new concepts and sharing the QueryableUtil. :)

Comment: Hey @Ivan, isn't the Parameter Sniffing Problem in context of stored procedures. But we are not using stored procedure here. Could you help me understand this.

Comment: Not really. It's related to every parametrized SQL query.

Comment: You can take a look at this thread [Entity Framework query performance differs extrem with raw SQL execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445373/entity-framework-query-performance-differs-extrem-with-raw-sql-execution/35523486#35523486)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use AsParallel() to enable multithreading execution of the linq query.
You should then check your tables' indexes to improve performances.