# DbContext timeout while running linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net5

I have the following async method that queries for some data on a database.

```
private async Task<List<MyObject>> GetTotalConcert(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, string[] name)
        {
            using (RegistrationDbContext context = new RegistrationDbContext())
            {
                IQueryable<MyObject> results;

                results = (from t1 in context.Table1
                           join t2 in context.Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id
                           where (t2.CreatedOn >= d1 && t2.CreatedOn < d2)
                           && (name.Contains(t2.Name))
                           && t1.EventName.Equals("Concert")
                           select new MyObject
                           {
                               Id = t2.Id,
                               EventName = t1.EventName,
                               Status = t2.Status,
                               ProjectName = t2.Name
                           });

                return await results.Distinct().ToAsyncEnumerable().ToList();
            }
        }
```

This code, fails with a timeout exception in cases where the date range is too wide. I tried to increase the timeout by doing this:

```
public class RegistrationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            base.Database.SetCommandTimeout(300);

        }
        // Some more code here....
    }
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here? If I run the SQL query on the database itself, it takes close to 18 seconds for the same date range...

I am using ASP.NET 5 MVC6 and EF7.

How can I get rid of the timeout exception for these cases where the time range is too wide and takes more time for the db to return the data?

Comment: 18 seconds ? You probably need to do some optmization on the db side and the query. do you have proper indexes ?

Comment: I do not own the database at all. This is something I can't change...

Comment: Try this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549640/how-to-set-commandtimeout-for-dbcontext

Comment: What approach, sorry? I can see different implementations on that question... Is the one marked as right answer?

Comment: What type is the database - SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the issue is related to so called [Parameter Sniffing Problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/), similar to [EntityFramework LINQ query count fails but query returns result. How to optimize LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069497/entityframework-linq-query-count-fails-but-query-returns-result-how-to-optimize/36070801#36070801).

You can take a modified version of the helper class from the link:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class QueryableUtils
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> dateSelector, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var startCond = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(dateSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(startDate));
        var endCond = Expression.LessThan(dateSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(endDate));
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(startCond, endCond), dateSelector.Parameters[0]);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> dateSelector, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var startCond = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(dateSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(startDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
        var endCond = Expression.LessThan(dateSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(endDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(startCond, endCond), dateSelector.Parameters[0]);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

then change your query to:

```
results = (from t1 in context.Table1
           join t2 in context.Table2.WhereIn(x => x.CreatedOn, d1, d2) on t1.Id equals t2.Id
           where (name.Contains(t2.Name))
           && t1.EventName.Equals("Concert")
           select new MyObject
           {
               Id = t2.Id,
               EventName = t1.EventName,
               Status = t2.Status,
               ProjectName = t2.Name
           });
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am having some trouble at the moment with the lambda expression that defines (x => x.CreatedOn, d1, d2). That gives me a build time error since it can't convert from DateTime? to DateTime. If I try to cast it or put x.CreatedOn.value, then I get a runtime error that says "Conversion failed when convertind date and/or time from character string."

Comment: So `CreatedOn` field is `DateTime?` ?

Comment: Yup, it seems to be of type DateTime?

Comment: Sorry for keep bothering but although that issue is resolved now, I am getting a new exception. The binary operator GreaterThanOrEqual is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' and 'System.DateTime'. I believe this is happening because on my model I have defined it as Nullable? EDIT: After getting rid of the Nullable on my   Model, the issue still persists. So maybe there is something else..

Comment: Are you using the exact updated method (with `typeof(DateTime?)` at the end of the two `Expression.Constant` methods)? I've tried it before posting in my EF and it works w/o problem.

Comment: Oops, I'm using EF6. Will try EF7 when have time.

Comment: Btw, don't change your model, the new function expects `CreatedOn` to be `DateTime?`. I've tested it with my table having nullable DateTime field.

Comment: Hehe, ok, but while waiting, try the last update - now there are two methods, one for `DateTime` and one for `DateTime?` field, so just pass your model property and the compiler will choose the right overload.

Comment: I found the issue was related to the db and the dates were a bit funky... your solution works perfectly though!